# debugging iptables when tunneling one VPN through another

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn, tunneling

I seek to tunnel one SSL VPN (F5, running on my debian laptop==`client`) through another (OpenVPN, running on a debian linode==`server`), but lose all client networking (including, e.g., `ping`) after the F5VPN connects. I'm not sure whether this is due to my OpenVPN configuration or my server's firewall/iptables, but suspect the latter. Unfortunately I am not knowledgeable regarding networking, so I'd appreciate any assistance you could provide.

I need to remotely (off the physical LAN) SSH into some firewalled compute clusters to do environmental modeling (e.g., [this](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/aqmeii-na_n2o/wiki/Home)). Formerly I could do this from my debian laptop using the [cluster-provider-mandated F5VPN](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linode_jumpbox_config/wiki/Home#rst-header-f5vpn-only-access), the client for which is known as the `F5NAP` (for "network access [browser] plugin." However, [access policy changed](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linode_jumpbox_config/wiki/Home#rst-header-aug-2014-policy-change) (notably to require a single registered IP#), so I can no longer do this "directly" (i.e., just running the F5VPN from my laptop). I seek to adapt to the new policy (and resume work on my project) by implementing a VPN tunnel from my client/laptop through a debian linode server/jumpbox. [Design details here](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linode_jumpbox_config/wiki/Home#rst-header-intended-solution), but my design can be roughly summarized with the following ASCII art:

```
                     <-MY CONTROL | AGENCY CONTROL->
                                  |                    firewall
+----------+      +-----------+   |   +---------------+   ||   +---------+
| laptop + |      | linode  + |   |   | remote-access |   ||   | cluster |
| F5NAP  + | <--> | OpenVPN   | <-|-> | website +     | <-||-> | node(s) |
| OpenVPN  |      | server  + |   |   | F5VPN server  |   ||   |         |
| client   |      | security  |   |   |               |   ||   |         |
+----------+      +-----------+   |   +---------------+   ||   +---------+
```

([Implementation details here](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linode_jumpbox_config/wiki/Home#rst-header-id6). Note that `F5NAP`==F5VPN client.) The good news is, the following sequence works: I can

1. [start an OpenVPN server on my linode](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linode_jumpbox_config/wiki/OpenVPN_install#rst-header-test-server-startup) (aka "the server")
2. [start an OpenVPN client on my laptop](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linode_jumpbox_config/wiki/OpenVPN_install#rst-header-test-client-startup), after which [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com) shows the IP# of the server (which is registered)
3. start the F5VPN client (an [F5NAP'ed Firefox](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linode_jumpbox_config/wiki/Home#rst-header-f5nap)), and from that still see the server's IP#.
4. using the F5VPN client, login to the agency's remote-access website, and bring up the F5VPN's control UI (e.g., to start/stop/logout).

The bad news (details [here](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linode_jumpbox_config/wiki/Home#rst-header-network-problem)) is, as soon as I start the F5VPN, and see status==Connected in its web UI, my client/laptop loses IP networking. I had originally thought this was just a DNS problem, but I cannot even `ping` IP#s, e.g.,

```
me@client:~ $ ping -c 4 141.101.120.15 # == www.whatismyip.com
PING 141.101.120.15 (141.101.120.15) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 141.101.120.15 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3022ms
```

(The only consolation here is that the network failure kills the tunnel, which causes my client to regain its networking ... but also its access to the registered IP#.)

I had thought that this problem was due to OpenVPN misconfiguration on my part, but now suspect that I need to tweak my [server firewall](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linode_jumpbox_config/downloads/server_iptables_L.txt) (which is `iptables`, running on Debian 7.8) in order to allow my OpenVPN configuration to work: see a client-commandline debugging session [here](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linode_jumpbox_config/downloads/client_networking_investigation.txt).

One more complication: [the F5VPN](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linode_jumpbox_config/wiki/Home#rst-header-f5vpn) is proprietary and not (IMHO) particularly well supported by either F5 (the vendor) or the cluster provider (their customer, aka "the agency"). Particularly, I don't know (but have asked) for the IP#(s) of the agency's VPN server: I only know the name (for which DNS tells me the IP# :-) of the remote-access website that I need to use to login to the F5VPN.

Comment: Bravo! +1 for the recursive nature of the task you want to do!  I have no experience with SSH tunneling, but I applaud your sense of style!

Comment: believe me, I wouldn't be trying to do this if they hadn't made me :-( I was quite happy directly shelling into the clusters ...